# Discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[a,b]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. If $a\in \mathcal{O}_K$ is integral, then $Disc(\mathbb{Z}[a])=\prod_{i<j}( a_i - a_j)^2$ where the $a_i$ are the conjugates of $a$.
Is there a similar formula for rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}[a,b]$ where $a,b$ are integrals?

If there isn't any "nice" formula, maybe there are nice upper q lower bounds? Clearly, we can give an upper bound using the discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[b]$, but can we use their discriminant to give a lower bound as well?